# What is the most efficient way to (pre)process large data sets stored in json?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, large-data

I have a json with 28k of objects written in 360k lines of code. I have a program which decodes the json and then works with decoded data (28k markers in google maps).

A function parsing the json is executed on every app launch which seems unnecessary (and slow). So I tried to load the data to arrays in separate swift file. But even to open a swift file with an array of 28k strings(4 characters each) takes much more time (tens of seconds) than to open a whole json file with 360k lines of code (which includes those 28k strings and 10pieces of information about each one) So I suppose the processing such raw array is slower than if json parsed and then read.

Why is it so and how to work with this kind of data in the most efficient way? Is it necessary to parse on every launch or how to preprocess the json to save some memory?

Comment: Load in batches and as needed, load more in batches.

Comment: Sounds nice, but could you be more specific?:) Is parsing the json on every launch a good approach or does some preprocessing make a noticeable difference?

Comment: "So I tried to load the data to arrays in separate swift file" - what exactly do you mean by that? do you mean that you have a global variable that is an array? @Eljer

Comment: I had but obviously it's a nogo:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any piece of your JSON, I'll assume you have something like this:

```
{    
fruits: {
    apples: [{
        color: "red",
        size: "20", // whatever unities
    }, {
        color: "green",
        size: "30",
    }, { /* ...  lots of apples ... */ }],
    bananas: [{
        oldness: 1,
        marks: 0
    }, {
        oldness: 3,
        marks: 4
    }, { /* ...  lots of bananas ... */ }],
    /* ... lots of fruits ... */
},
vegetables: {
    /* ... same as fruits ... */
},
/* ... lots of other stuff ... */
}
```

What you can do, you can make a file tree based on your data and access it easier when you need it. Let's suppose you need at T0 - which is the start of your application - only the `apples` data, then you can just load the `apples.json` from `fruits` folder.

An example of a file tree you can have is given exactly by the JSON itself, you can have something like:

```
data
| - fruits
|   | - apples.json
|   | - bananas.json
|
| - vegetables
|   | - cucumbers.json
|   | - i hope you get the idea
```

Comment: Ok, my tree would be something like below. I have to process the whole json to get coordinates before I can filter which airport markers to show on map..

Comment: ```
airport1
|  -  latitude
|  -  longitude
|  -  elevation 
|  -  …
|  -  …
airport2
|  -  latitude
|  -  longitude
|  -  elevation 
|  -  …
|  -  …
airport3
|  -  latitude
|  -  longitude
|  -  elevation 
|  -  …
|  -  …
```

Comment: Ok, sounds good. Preprocess your data into some chunks. You can define your folders by continent, or states, or whatever suits you the best. Try to get the first view of the map, get these boundaries: (min_lat, min_long, max_lat, max_long). See in what region they are placed based on your chunks, load those airports first, while loading all the airports in the background. When the view is changed, check if your chunk is loaded, if not, make it load with priority.

Comment: Thanks, now I see that my json can be massively improved.